# Why does this `pip install` command fail?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pypi

Background: I first published [this package](https://pypi.org/project/django-simplecms/) on PyPi in January 2021. However, the following `pip install` command now fails when I run it on a Linode VPS:

```
$ pip install django-simplecms
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-simplecms (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-simplecms
```

When I run it from my home computer, it installs the package successfully. In both cases I am using `pip` version 21.1.3 (latest) in a freshly made virtualenv. How could this be?

Comment: what python version are you running? Are you using python>=3.8?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy, or using a (partial) PyPi mirror?

Comment: Python version 3.7.3 (Debian Stable) which is indeed rather old. I am not behind a proxy that I know of. How can I see if/which PyPi mirror is being used by `pip`?

Comment: Did you try installing with pip3? Try:  `pip3 install django-simplecms`

Comment: I'm inside a Python 3 virtualenv, so I don't think there should be a difference. Nevertheless, I tried it with `pip3` and it also failed.

Comment: As a rule, *always* run `python3 -m pip`, since you can never be sure which exact version of Python is used by the `pip` executable. That said, virtualenvs are *less* unreliable, assuming you've entered it correctly and aren't mixing Python versions inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me why, but the following command bypasses the problem:

```
pip install -i https://pypi.org/pypi django-simplecms
```

According to [pip's documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#install-index-url), the `-i, --index-url` argument is used to specify the index and defaults to https://pypi.org/simple. When I changed this to https://pypi.org/pypi the package could be installed.

I guess my package is listed on PyPI Warehouse and not on PyPI Simple?